# dplyr: manipulate function with multiple arguments by groups

Tags: r, dplyr

With the robCompositions package, I need to impute missing values on a group basis. For example, with the iris dataset.

```
library(robCompositions)
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

# Insert random NAs
for (i in 1:4) {
  n_NA = sample(0:10, 1) 
  index_NA = sample(1:nrow(iris), n_NA)
  iris[index_NA, i] = NA
}
```

This is where I have no idea which manip to use...

```
impfunc <- function(x) x %.% 
  regroup(list(...)) %.% 
  mutate(impKNNa(x[,-5], k=6, metric="Euclidean"))
impfunc(iris, "Species")

iris %.% group_by(Species) %.% mutate(impKNNa(iris[,-5], k=6, metric="Euclidean"))
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the the do() function. It allows you to apply any arbitrary function to a grouped data frame.

You'll also want to extract not just the output from impKNNa but specifically impKNNA$xImp which is the altered data frame.

The other issue is that impKNNA doesn't want any variables except the numeric variables of interest and do() won't remove the categorical variables. So perhaps a solution is to write a wrapper function for impKNNA that will remove categorical variables and return xIMP, and use do() to apply that to a grouped data frame.